# Cannot install module on openERP

Tags: module, installation, odoo, project-management

I have a problem in using openERP.

I uninstalled the base kanban module by accident, but I've succeeded to install it back:

But then my installed project management got uninstalled automatically, and now I can't install it back. It says:

```
"Constraint Error

 You can not have two users with the same login !"
```

I've been looking for solutions through Google but I haven't found any.

Answer (score 0):

"You can not have two users with the same login !" error raise in two condition, either in demo data you have define two or more users with same login or the user with this login already exits in db and it again going to crate user with same login,

please check it

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

"You can not have two users with the same login !" is an sql_constraint defined in `res_users` model. There must be a record in `res_users` in your database which has the `login` value as of the one you are creating. Also check that the one in the database may be `active=False`, so it will not appear in the normal tree view, but you can check it by adding an advanced filter in the view.